# rails - How do I set the id value of new record of model in has many/belongs to relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I'm trying to create a record that in in a has_many and belongs_to relationship

user hasmany posts and posts belongto user

```
@post = Post.new( params[:post], :user_id => current_user.id )
@post.save
```

but I'm keep getting a wrong number of arguments error.

Can i set the user_id field of the Post model automatically somehow?  I'm using Devise which is where the current_user call comes from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple more ways:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.user_id = current_user.id
@post.save
```

Or:

```
@post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
@post.save
```

Answer (score 3):

Merge the `params[:post]` hash with `{:user_id => current_user.id}`:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post].merge({:user_id => current_user.id}))
@post.save
```

See [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002880)

Answer (score -2):

If you're using simple has_many and belongs_to associations there needn't be a post_id column in the users table. There need only be a user_id column in the posts table

With that you can do :

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.user_id = session[:user_id] #or an equivalent.
@post.save
@user.posts << @post
```

Comment: This is backwards and wrong. The OP's schema is correct. Your sample code will not do what you describe.

Comment: @Jimmy - Sorry about that. I got slightly muddled. Have corrected my error. Thanks though.

Comment: 4th line in the code isn't necessary - adding the user_id to the post automatically creates the association with the user. :)